# sql server permissions

Tags: windows, sql-server-2005

Hi How can I set permissions againt existing windows groups in sql server 2005

Answer (score 0):

Expand the Security in Management studio, Right click on Logins and select new, Hit the Search button next to Login Name,

hit the Advanced button
Click on Find now
Your Groups/logins will appear in the search results.
Select Groups/Logins

close all open dialogs by clicking ok
Now you have a login

Associate the login / group to Databas object(s) by right clicking on the Database (name) and permissions- You can also associate permission to child objects of the database (Tables/Sps etc) individualy

Comment: Thanks I have done that but when it comes to assigning the permissions, Sql does not seem to be able to find the logins for Windows group, It only seems to be able to find User and Database role object types and the new login created is never found

Comment: @ruben - are you working directly on the server, or through a remote management console? Either way, are you logged in with a domain account, or a local account?